# Como recorrer un array para insertar datos de una tabla HTML a MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Soy nuevo en esto de los arreglos, y quiero saber como recorrerlos correctamente para hacer una inserción de datos basada en el contenido de una table, ¿como debe ser el código para ejecutar los query correspondientes?:

GuardarFactura.php

```
<?php
$htmlContent = file_get_contents("FrmClientes.php");

    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);

    $Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th');
    $Detail = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');

//#Get header name of the table
    foreach($Header as $NodeHeader) 
    {
            $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
    }
    print_r($aDataTableHeaderHTML); die();

    //#Get row data/detail table without header name as key
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail) 
    {
            $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
            $i = $i + 1;
            $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
    }
    print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();

    //#Get row data/detail table with header name as key and outer array index as row number
    for($i = 0; $i < count($aDataTableDetailHTML); $i++)
    {
            for($j = 0; $j < count($aDataTableHeaderHTML); $j++)
            {
                    $aTempData[$i][$aDataTableHeaderHTML[$j]] = $aDataTableDetailHTML[$i][$j];
            }
    }
    $aDataTableDetailHTML = $aTempData; unset($aTempData);
    print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();
?>
```

FrmClientes.php //El contenido de los td es obtenido durante la ejecución del codigo, pero para hacer pruebas puse esos valores.

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="adicionados">          
<table class="table" id="tabla">
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>ID Articulo</th>
    <th>Descripcion</th>
    <th>Valor Venta</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td id="Sid">dw</td>
    <td id="Sdescripcion">ads</td>
    <td id="Svlrventa">ads</td>
    <td id="Scantidad">da</td>
    <td id="Ssubtotal">ad</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

[image: Diseño de base de datos]

Los th hacen referencia a los campos de las tablas y los td a lo que debe ser insertado respectivamente

Comment: espero te sirva esta guia :https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1074174/Simple-Way-to-Convert-HTML-Table-Data-into-PHP-Arr